# How to group the information respectively with comma separator in the input?

Tags: bash, shell

My file name is myInfo.txt under the current directory: `DIR="$(pwd)";`

inside it has:

```
1000 at num 2049 28 2068100
1000 at num 2049 28 2623200
1000 at num 2049 28 2833000
1000 at num 2049 28 3499700
1000 at num 2051 28 2453500
1000 at num 2051 28 2969400
1000 at num 2051 28 3071300
1000 at num 2051 28 3838200
```

Now I used the bash script sequentially:

```
DIR="$(pwd)";
array=(2049 2151);
for k in "${array[@]}"; do
  grep "at num ${k}" myInfo.txt | cut -d' ' -f 6 > ${DIR}/Info/nums/${k}.out
done
```

and group the 6th column information in each row like `2068100 2623200......` into the file `2049.out` and `2051.out` respectively under the folder `${DIR}/Info/nums/`

My question is: Can I use comma separator like follows to get the same functionality as before:

```
for k in "${array[@]}"; do
  grep "at num ${k}" myInfo.txt | cut -d',' -f 6 > ${DIR}/Info/nums/${k}.out
done
```

I tried to re-generate the myInfo.txt to satisfy the above command:

```
1000,at num 2049,28,2068100
1000,at num 2049,28,2623200
1000,at num 2049,28,2833000
1000,at num 2049,28,3499700
1000,at num 2051 28,2453500
1000,at num 2051 28,2969400
1000,at num 2051 28,3071300
1000,at num 2051 28,3838200
```

and tried to group the information same as before. But it seems that the `cut -d',' -f 6` cannot get the same functionality as `cut -d' ' -f 6`.

I wonder if the "cut -d',' -f 6" is valid? If it is valid, which kind of format of information should I re-generate in the myInfo.txt file? Thank you.

Comment: you only have 2 or 3 comma, so you have 3 or 4 fields when you consider comma as a separator... so -f6 will fetch nothing

Comment: Sorry, the data should be like this.
1000,at num 2049 28,2068100
1000,at num 2049 28,2623200
1000,at num 2049 28,2833000
1000,at num 2049 28,3499700
1000,at num 2051 28,2453500
1000,at num 2051 28,2969400
1000,at num 2051 28,3071300
1000,at num 2051 28,3838200

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fix your problem in (at least) two ways:

Either you replace each space in `myInfo.txt` with a comma, and not just some, or you use the 4th column now (because when using the `,` as the delimiter, each column is separated by a column).

In any case, you should fix up your file so that your comma separation is consistent across all lines (right now you sometimes have 3, sometimes 2 commas).

Comment: now after modification, can use cut -d',' -f 4 to get the data

Answer (score 1):

If your input record is structured like this:

```
1000,at num 2049,28,2068100
```

Then you need

```
cut -d',' -f 4
```

To extract 4th column.

However if you want to use:

```
cut -d',' -f 6
```

then input record should be formatted like this:

```
1000,at,num,2049,28,2068100
```